Write to a gdb in FME using a template but creating a new gdb
I have a geodatabase set up already as a template with the correct layer types and names. I use this template because the geodatabase has related tables and connections that output best if the relationship is set up in the goedatabase before the data is created/added. I'd like to be able to use this template each time I output new features to a new geodatabase,but not by overwriting the template. In short, I want to have a blank template always ready to use. Is there a way to set up the featurewriter so that it uses the template of an existing geodatabase but creates a new one? Ideally in the same location the data is being read from (by using the file path attributes)

Can't you make a processing step to copy the template database, then just add features to the copy?

yes use the filecopy writer at the start of your workflow see https://community.safe.com/data-7/using-filecopy-writer-to-move-fgdb-source-folder-gets-left-behind-9139 *make sure copy subfolders is set to yes.
